# Firestore invalid Query for Orderd By?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query a collection of posts. Each post has a watched by section, and if the watched by section contains the user then the query should return the value. However, when I run the query :

```swift
 let postsReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
    let watchingQuery = postsReference.order(by: "watchedBy/\(UID!)").start(at: [""])

    watchingQuery.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in

            if (diff.type == .added) {

            }
            if (diff.type == .modified) {

            }
            if (diff.type == .removed) {

            }
        }
```

I get the error `Invalid field path (watchedBy/BmVoasdfa34fdtiucWSb8XPPM42). Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']''`. The equivalent firebase query worked fine:

```swift
 let watchedByQuery = postReference.queryOrdered(byChild: "/watchedBy/" + UID!).queryStarting(atValue: "")
```

I have tried changing the code to `let watchingQuery = postsReference.order(by: "watchedBy.\(UID!)").start(at: [""])`. This query works, but nothing returns from the FireStore.

Edit :

Have tried :

```swift
  let postsReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
    let watchingQuery = postsReference.whereField("watchedBy."+(UID!), isGreaterThan: "")
```

But still returning empty .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up that my posting method was still the same as the firebase method which did a multiplication update. Thus, the posting mechanism was posting to the wrong path.